# Jenkins: how to use variables inside agent docker args?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins doesn't want to use any variables inside agent docker args section, except main Jenkins variables, such a `JENKINS_URL`.

Containerized Jenkins 2.152. Trying to start docker agent with custom args using variables. Tried to use Groove var, environment var like `env.Var`, environment var like `${Var}`. All of them were used as names, but not as their values.

**Jenkinsfile**

```sh
    Gpath = "/var/log:/opt/gpath"
    pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image "bash:latest"
            args '--network proxy_nw -v Gpath -v ${Ppath} -v env.Ppath2 -v /var/log:/${NODE_LABELS}'
        }
    }
    environment {
        Ppath = "/var/log:/opt/ppath"
        Ppath2 = "/var/log:/opt/ppath2"
    }
        stages {
            stage ('main') {
                steps {
                   script {
                    sh 'echo "Ppath= " ${Ppath} "; Ppath2= " ${Ppath2} "; NODE_LABELS= " ${NODE_LABELS}'
                    sh 'printenv'
                    input message: "wait"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins console output**

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 --network proxy_nw -v Gpath -v ${Ppath} -v env.Ppath2 -v /var/log:/${NODE_LABELS}
```

As you can see, I used several variables inside the args section.
Ok, because of single quotes it looks like reasonable that the Groovy vars go like names. We can see it at the Jenkins console output.
But environment variables are not working too. They are actually available  inside the docker container, not at Jenkins level.
So,how to define variables for the args section of agent docker directive?

Answer (score 10):

I found workaround.

I added to the top level `agent none` and put all my stages into the stage with just container declaration. Yes, it is because we can put `stages` inside `stage`

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
    WORKDIR = getVar(G_workdir)
    DIRDOUBLE = getVar(G_dirdouble)
    }
    stages {
        stage('build container up') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image G_container
                    args '--network proxy_nw -v ${DIRDOUBLE}'
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage('Initialise') {
                        steps {
            ........
```