# Parameterize docker agent image argument with user input in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses a Docker agent. I would like for the user to be able to specify which tag from the image repository is used for the pipeline. In the example below, the pipeline has an argument called `tag` that the user can specify, which is appended to (concatenated) the `image` argument to the docker agent. The full example is specified below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(String tag = 'latest') {
    pipeline {
        agent {
            docker {
                image "analytics/rsc:${tag}"
                registryUrl 'my.local.registry'
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This throws the error

```
...12: Invalid config option "call" for agent type "docker". Valid config options are [image, alwaysPull, args, containerPerStageRoot, customWorkspace, label, registryCredentialsId, registryUrl, reuseNode] @ line 12, column 17.
                   image analytics/rsc:${tag}
```

I have tried other variations for the `image` argument, including

```
image "analytics/rsc:" + "${tag}"
```

and

```
image 'analytics/rsc:' + tag
```

none of which have worked (I get errors similar to that of the first example, where the variable `tag` is not evaluated and instead the literal text `"tag"` is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem that is reported as [**JENKINS-42369**](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42369). Unfortunately, I don't think they will fix it any time soon, given that it was reported 6 years ago.

You can try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53923775/9213148), but workarounds do not work in all cases.